# Filter a list in Python to only include the email address from a DynamoDB scan

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb

I am new to Python and need some help with extracting specific text from a list of strings.

```
import boto3

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('Student')
response = table.scan(
    ProjectionExpression='Email',
)
items = response['Items']
print(items)
```

I am getting the follow results from print 
[{'Email': 'test@test.com'}, {'Email': 'test1@test.com'}]

I am trying to remove everything but the email address from this list so I end up with just a list of emails.  I can only find information on using regular expression on a string but this is a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're getting is a `list` of `dict` structures. You can transform them using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```py
emails = [ email_dict['Email'] for email_dict in response['Items'] ]
```

Essentialy you iterate the list, and for each dictionary you fetch the entry by key 'Email', putting all those entries in a separate list.

Comment: One more question, If I wanted to keep this as a list of dict structures, how would that look?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
[x['Email'] for x in items]
```

In your code, it will be:

```
items = [x['Email'] for x in response['Items']]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I am a bit new to python.  Could you be a bit more specific, where and how that is placed in the code?

Comment: @KevinBraga Updated my answer with where it goes in your code.